# Elevation profile of earth

Tags: dem, topography, profile

Where can I find elevation data for the entire earth so that for a given location (coordinate) on the earth, I can find out the elevation of that particular location?

In particular, I am curious, what is the best resolution I can possibly achieve in this generality?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question.

Comment: If the elevation data you seek is open data then I think the place to ask the first of your three questions is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Try GEBCO for bathymetry:
https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/

And these handy tile grabbers for SRTM data from Derek Watkins:

30m resolution: https://dwtkns.com/srtm30m/

90m resolution: https://dwtkns.com/srtm/

Edit: looks like the 90m version has broken as of Jan 2021.  He now links to CGIAR:
https://cgiarcsi.community/data/srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database-v4-1/

Comment: thank you, since the files on the first website that are named something like GEBCO_2020, i wonder if they are actually from 2020?

Comment: I am asking this, since it says here that this SRTM data is actually from 2000 https://www2.jpl.nasa.gov/srtm/

Comment: Further GEBCO documentation is available here: https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/gebco_2020/

Answer (score 2):

I agree with mikeLdub, 30m is the best you will get for a global DEM. It stops however at 60°N.

If you need elevation data of the Arctic region, check ArcticDEM: https://www.pgc.umn.edu/data/arcticdem/ It is a very high resolution (2meters) elevation dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way without implying downloading any DEM or use of (specialized)  GIS software is just to browse [Google Earth](https://www.google.com/intl/en/earth/): it shows you the elevation of the point where the mouse hovers:

[image]

Comment: right, but if I want to externally access google's data, I need to pay right? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/elevation

Comment: Of course, this is a quick&dirty approack to get the elevation of just a few points, not bulk providing of elevation data for lists of coordinates.

Comment: thank you, do you know how often google updates their maps? Let's say there would be some mining going on now and people would dig a hole, would it be visible eventually?

Comment: You can see the date when the picture was taken at the bottom as well: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxTQv.jpg - here the example of the newly built bridge from Russia to Crimea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_Bridge